# How can we pause/resume WebDriver test execution on press of a button

Tags: multithreading, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I want to pause /resume my webdriver test case execution on press of a button.

The way i come up is to use Thread class suspend and resume methods. But i want to make sure that it should not pause while webdriver is typing text or something. As if it will do the browser may loose the focus from that point. So i want to ensure atomic execution of element.sendKeys or element.click.

Please suggest any ideas???

Answer (score 2):

Just run the test in debug mode. Then you can just suspend the entire JVM. This will have the effect of pausing WebDriver.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option here is to implement your own synchronization and start/stop around Selenium. One way to achieve this is to protect every call to a WebDriver API method with a *monitor* and a boolean flag to indicate that some other instance would like to suspend test execution:

```
private boolean suspend = false;

private Object monitor = new Object();
```

Your code before each API call could look as follows:

```
synchronized (monitor) {
    if (suspend) {
        try {
            monitor.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // thrown if someonelse calls notify
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to suspend test execution, you need to have someone (i.e. another Thread) execute the following code:

```
synchronized (monitor) {
    suspend = true;
}
```

To continue again, you would need to execute the following code:

```
synchronized (monitor) {
    monitor.notifyAll();
}
```

Thats just a very simple solution. There are more sophisticated synchronization styles, but this one should be sufficient.